# In Grafana when 2 template variables from Prometheus change then 1 template variable from Data Source changes too

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

In Grafana v9.3.4

I have the following 2 template variables named `instance` and `mssql_instance`.

The first one returns the instance (e.g. "winserver") and the second one return the SQL instances of the instance "winserver" (e.g. "mssqlserver", "dev"). Both of them are coming from Prometheus.

I have another template variable named `sql_datasource` which returns all the SQL data sources of Grafana (e.g. "winserver_mssqlserver", "winserver_dev", "winserver2_mssqlserver", "winserver2_server2").

In my dashboard I have mixed panels, few of them  project metrics from Prometheus and the rest of them project TSQL Queries.

I have implement the Prometheus variables in the Prometheus panels like this:

```
mssql_user_connections_per_database{instance=~"${instance}:.+",mssql_instance=~"$mssql_instance"}
```

So when I change the template variables (`instance` & `mssql_instance`) all the panel variables are changing accordingly.

I have also implement the SQL data source variable in the SQL panels but this time I have put the variable in the data source field like the following: `${sql_datasource}`.

As an addition I have implement a 4th template variable named `sql_datasource_auto` that combines the 2 variables `instance` and `mssql_instance` in order its output to be the same as the `sql_datasource`. And it looks like the following:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('${instance}', '_', '${mssql_instance}') AS sql_datasource_auto
```

If I choose `instance` = winserver and `mssql_instance` = dev, then the `sql_datasource_auto` variable will be winserver_dev.

And here comes my question.

Is there any way that, the `sql_datasource` can always have the same value with `sql_datasource_auto`?

I tried to find a way in order to combine the values but I didn't succeed.

I don't know if what I am asking is possible because the variables are coming from 2 different data sources.

Comment: First of all, why don't use just use `$sql_datasource_auto` instead of `$sql_datasource`? Or even `${instance}_${mssql_instance}` instead both of them?

Comment: In the panel editor the available Data Source options I have are the following:

${sql_datasource}, 
Prometheus, 
`winserver_mssqlserver`,
`winserver_dev`, 
`winserver2_mssqlserver`,
`winserver2_server2`

Comment: You don't need to link two variables, you just need to remove `$sql_datasource` and then rename `$sql_datasource_auto` to `$sql_datasource`.

Comment: Even if I remove the `$sql_datasource` variable from the dashboard and rename the `$sql_datasource_auto` variable to `$sql_datasource`. I will not be able to see the `$sql_datasource` (previously named `$sql_datasource_auto`) variable in the panel editor because the panel editor shows only the data sources from the Grafana and the template variables that have as a variable type the value Data Source and the `$sql_datasource` ( prev `$sql_datasource_auto`)  is a query not a Data Source type. That's the reason why I need to link the `$sql_datasource` and the `$sql_datasource_auto` variables.

Comment: Aha, I understand what you want now. Afaik, there is now way to create such a linkage: data source variables are very limited in general. But you could try to do it in reverse: allow user to select data source and later based on it's value calculate `${instance}` and `${mssql_instance}`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I will give it a try and I will provide some feedback!